# Magento javascript cookies

Tags: template, theme

I am trying to get rid of as much inline javascript as i can in my theme.  Looking at the Mage cookies js that is included in the head template, I cant see where this is used.

Can anyone explain if this is absolutely required, or if it is present for some other legacy/bc reason and can be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick search brought up a usage in `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/notices.phtml`